# Using mod_rewrite to remove PHP path detail

Tags: mod-rewrite

I can't seem to get Example 1 to turn into Example 2 using mod_rewrite.

Example 1

```
http://www.example.com/info/index.php?uid=123
```

Example 2

```
http://www.example.com/123
```

Mod rewrite code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /info

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /info/index.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com(:80)?$ [NC]        
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^uid=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/info/index\.php$ http://www.example.com/%1? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: you must of mis read my question I want the last piece of code to work.

Comment: how do you invoke the url? www.example.com/info/index.php?uid=xxxx or example.com/info/index.php?uid=xxxx

Comment: I use `www.example.com/info/index.php?uid=xxxx`

Comment: and you want it to redirect to www.example.com/xxxx is it correct?

Comment: try disabling the rewritebase directive, if you are not aliasing the "/info" directory please. The rules work in a domain I own right now, so it's correct. The only difference is the rewritebase atm

Comment: enable the RewriteLogLevel 9 directive and cut & paste the log output

Comment: I'm not a mod rewrite expert exactly how would I enable RewriteLogLevel 9?

Comment: simply add the directive after RewriteEngine on, in a separate line. example: RewriteEngine on RewriteLog my-rewrite.log RewriteLogLevel 9 each directive in a different line of course

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error

Comment: there is some problem with mod_rewrite i'm afraid, then... the directives are standard mod_rewrite directives, it shouldn't crash

Comment: try disable `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: try writing the RewriteLog directive in this way: RewriteLog "/full/path/to/rewrite.log", changing /full/path/to with your log full path